# Switch To Linux Containers and 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Windows Server 2019 version 1809. When I click switch to Linux Containers, I am getting,

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
job failed with message: 'DockerDesktopVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID 1456B986-2FAE-42E4-B86E-17AE68743A52)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'DockerDesktopVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID 1456B986-2FAE-42E4-B86E-17AE68743A52).
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.HandleUpdatedJob(CIMConcreteJob updatedJob) in C:\workspaces\PR-21378\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 780
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<HandleMaybeAsyncJob>d__40.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-21378\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 714
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Backend.HyperVInfrastructure.<StartVMAsync>d__32.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-21378\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperVInfrastructure.cs:line 554
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Backend.HyperV.<StartAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-21378\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV\HyperV.cs:line 106
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Backend.HttpAPI.HyperVController.<StartAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-21378\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HttpAPI\HyperVController.cs:line 49
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
```

As per Microsoft page, Windows Server 2019 is supported https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux

`com.docker.diagnose.exe` check saying,

`com.docker.vpnkit.exe is not running`
`* com.docker.proxy.exe is not running`